# Mongoid embedded documents and Rails strong parameters not working

Tags: json, angularjs, http, json-api

I have a 1-N relationship in Mongoid/Rails:

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :people, class_name: 'Person'
end

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :first_name, type: String
  embedded_in :company, class_name: 'Company', inverse_of: 'people'
end
```

Now I can successfully create a Company as follows in the console; for example:

```
> c = Company.new(name: 'GLG', :people => [{first_name: 'Jake'}])  # OK!
> c.people                                                         # OK!
```

Then I have a JSON API controller to update a company, along the lines of:

```
# PUT /api/companies/:id
def update
  if Company.update(company_params)
    # ... render JSON
  else
    # ... render error
  end
end

private

def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:name, :people => [:first_name])
end
```

Now, when the PUT request comes in from the frontend, the company_params is always missing the :people attribute. Rails log says:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"5436fbc64a616b5240050000", "name"=>"GLG", "people"=>[{"first_name"=>"Jake"}], "company"=>{"name"=>"GLG"}}
```

I don't get an "Unpermitted parameters" warning. I've tried every conceivable way of permitting the people field and it still doesn't get included.

```
params.require(:company).permit!
```

Results in the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept [nested_attributes](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/nested_attributes.html) on assignment

```
 class Company
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :people, class_name: 'Person'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people
end
```

Comment: No effect. The params already have this issue when they hit the update method.